# Как связывать таблицы в Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Добрый день, в очередной раз попал в тупик и не знаю как быть, помогите плиззз
есть две таблицы, использую spring и hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cwd_user")
public class cwd_user {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String user_name;

    @Column(name = "display_name")
    private String display_name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "author")
    private Set<Worklog> worklog;

    //гетеры и сеттеры
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "worklog")
public class Worklog {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "STARTDATE")
    private Date startdate;

    @Column(name = "timeworked")
    private int timeworked;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_name")
    private cwd_user cwd_user;

    //геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Мне нужно связать их по полям `worklog.author = cwd_user.user_name`, но перечитав много статей, у меня так и не вышло ничего

Помогите пожалуйста, как правильно указать аннотацию и так же, как правильно в самом запросе писать inner join? 
нужно ли писать `from worklog w inner join cwd_user s on w.author = s.user_name`?

причем мне нужно из `cwd_user` вывести `display_name`, а из `worklog` вывести `timeworked` и `startdate`. И вывести все на веб-страницу

Сделал вот так(связь Один ко многим, то есть в таблице cwd_user только одно значение)
В класс таблицы cwd_user добавил аннотацию @OneToMany

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cwduser", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Worklog> worklogList;

public Set<Worklog> getWorklog() {
    return worklogList;
}

public void setWorklog(Set<Worklog> worklogList) {
    this.worklogList = worklogList;
}
```

в класс Worklog

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_name")
private cwd_user cwduser;

public cwd_user getCwd_user() {
    return cwduser;
}

public void setCwd_user(cwd_user cwduser) {
    this.cwduser = cwduser;
}
```

Запустил тестирование на запросе `from Worklog l where l.author =`, пишет `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'user_name'.`

Запустил с запросом `from Worklog l inner join cwd_user c on l.author = c.user_name where l.author =` пишет `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 80 [from domain.Worklog l inner join cwd_user c on l.author = c.user_name where l.author =`

Кто может помочь, помогите понять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос больше неактуален. Я разобрался как использовать связи many to one, one to many, many to many, one to one.

То есть нужно указывать джой не на поле в другой таблице, как делал я, а как раз на поле в главной таблице.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private cwd_user cwd_user;
```

Создает переменную сущности с которой связываем наше поле.

только в таблице cwd_user, в моем случае, поле с которым связь дет помечено аннотацией @id

```
@Id
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String user_name;
```

Comment: Если вы решили вопрос самостоятельно, стоит добавить свой развернутый ответ.